# Where to find authorization code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth, office365, access-token

For my app I need to invoke `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` and for this, one of the parameters that I need is an authorisation code, however I do not know where to find this authorization code or how to acquire it.

Does anyone know how I can get this authorization code? Does it come from the AuthroizationContext object?

**Notes:** using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory version 3.5.207081303-alpha

Comment: http://dev.office.com